# Sum of k-largest eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix as an SDP

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I found the following statement from a google search. If $S_k(\mathbf{X})$ is the sum of the $k$ largest eigenvalues of a symmetric $m\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$, then,$$S_k(\mathbf{X}) \leq t$$ is true iff

$$ t - k s - \mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{Z}) \geq 0 \\ \mathbf{Z} \geq 0 \\ \mathbf{Z} - \mathbf{X} + s\mathbf{I}_m \geq 0$$, where $s$ hasn't been described. I tried with $s$ as a positive variable in CVX and it worked and I could calculate the $k$ largest eigenvalues of $\mathbf{X}$.

I seem to be going around in circles trying to prove this one. I would like to prove it on my own. Can anyone provide a starting direction or the first few lines of the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: In fact, this is exactly what CVX uses to implement this function in `lambda_sum_largest`. I'm glad I didn't have to prove it. :-) $s$ is just a free variable (i.e., no need to require it to be non-negative; in fact I am not convinced it will always work if you do).

Comment: @MichaelGrant I was going through the code of the `lambda_sum_largest` function and found that it was using the `eig` command in MATLAB. Does CVX alter the way MATLAB uses the `eig` command? Is there any place where the implementation you have mentioned is visible? Thanks :)

Comment: It only uses `eig` for constant inputs. Look in the `@cvx` subdirectories for the CVX-specific implementations.

Comment: can we think like this? Say $s=0$, then $Z\geq X$ implies $trace(Z)\geq trace(X)$ (can't see a way to prove it though!!). Then $t\geq trace(Z)\geq trace(X) \geq S_k(X)$.

Comment: btw, I guess $X$ should be non-negative definite for the above argument to work, if it works at all!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We'll start with the following expression for $S_k(\mathbf{X})$ as a maximum sum over $k$ orthonormal vectors:
$$\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{v}_1\ldots\mathbf{v}_k} \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbf{v}_i^T \mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}_i\\
\mathbf{v}_i^T \mathbf{v}_j = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \ne j\end{cases}
\end{gathered}$$
If we collect the vectors in the $k \times m$ matrix $\mathbf{V}$, in matrix notation this is:
$$\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{V}} \text{ trace}(\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{V})\\
\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{I}_k
\end{gathered}$$
Since this is a nonconvex problem, we'll consider a convex relaxation. Note that $\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{I}_k$ only if $\mathbf{0} \preceq  \mathbf{V} \mathbf{V}^T \preceq \mathbf{I}$ and $\text{trace}(\mathbf{V} \mathbf{V}^T)=k$. So letting $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V} \mathbf{V}^T$, we consider the following SDP which is a convex relaxation of the above:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_\mathbf{A} \ \text{trace}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X})\\
\mathbf{0} \preceq \mathbf{A} \preceq \mathbf{I} \\
\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}) = k
\end{gathered}
$$
Then we take the dual (and reformulate slightly) to get:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\min_{\mathbf{Z},s} \ \text{trace}(\mathbf{Z})+ks\\
\mathbf{Z} \succeq \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{Z} + s \mathbf{I} \succeq \mathbf{X}
\end{gathered}
$$
Now that we have the above SDP primal-dual pair, we can prove that their optimal value is $S_k(\mathbf{X})$ just by constructing optimal points. Suppose $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{U}\text{ diag}(\lambda)\mathbf{U}^T$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is an orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors and $\mathbf{\lambda}$ is the vector of eigenvalues sorted in decreasing order, that is $\lambda_i\ge\lambda_{i+1}$. Then let 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{A}^*&=\mathbf{U}\text{ diag}(\mathbf{1}_k,\mathbf{0}_{m-k})\mathbf{U}^T\\
\mathbf{Z}^*&=\mathbf{U}\text{ diag}((\lambda-\lambda_k \mathbf{1})_+)\mathbf{U}^T\\
s^*&=\lambda_k
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, $(\cdot)_+$ is the positive part of a vector (it sets the negative components to zero). One can check that these points are feasible for their respective problems. Also we check the values of the objectives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{X})&=\text{trace}(\mathbf{U}\text{ diag}(\lambda)\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U} \text{ diag}(\mathbf{1}_k,\mathbf{0}_{m-k})\mathbf{U}^T)\\
&=\text{trace}(\text{diag}(\lambda)\text{ diag}(\mathbf{1}_k,\mathbf{0}_{m-k}))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i\\
&=S_k(\mathbf{X})\\
\text{trace}(\mathbf{Z}^*)+ks^* &= k\lambda_k  +\sum_{i=1}^m(\lambda_i-\lambda_k)_+\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k((\lambda_i-\lambda_k)_+ + \lambda_k)\\
&=S_k(\mathbf{X})
\end{aligned}
$$
Recall that all dual feasible points give a bound for the primal and vice-versa. Since these points give the same value of the objective for their respective problems, they must be optimal. Therefore $S_k(\mathbf{X})$ is the optimal value for both SDPs.

Comment: +1, Then $\mathbf{A}$ will be the sum of $k$ rank-one positive semi-definite matrices, where each matrix is the outer product of unit-norm eigenvectors corresponding to the $k$ largest eigenvalues, Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. (Though to be a complete proof you also need to consider the case of nonunique eigenvalues, but it's a straightforward generalization.)

Comment: Can you please take a look at the comment I have posted on the OP's question? does it help?