# Minimizing the second largest eigenvalue as an SDP with a rank-$1$ constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I found this interesting SDP exercise problem on minimizing the second largest eigenvalue of

$$ A(\mathbf{x}) = A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i A_i $$

where $A_0, A_1, \dots, A_n$ are given real symmetric matrices. The given hint says this can be reformulated as an SDP with a rank-$1$ constraint.

I tried to solve this by following this [similar thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045963/339790). I first reformulated the original problem as follows

$$\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{v}_2^T A(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_2\\
\mathbf{v}_1^T \mathbf{v}_1 = 1,\  \mathbf{v}_2^T \mathbf{v}_2 = 1,\ \mathbf{v}_1^T \mathbf{v}_2 = 0\\ \mathbf{v}_1^TA(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_1\geq \mathbf{v}_2^TA(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}_2
\end{gathered}$$

using orthonormal vectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$. Then, I defined two rank-$1$ matrices

$$\mathbf{W}_1=\mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v}_1^T$$

$$\mathbf{W}_2=\mathbf{v}_2\mathbf{v}_2^T$$

and get

$$\max_{\mathbf{W}_1,\mathbf{W}_2,\mathbf{x}} \text{ trace}(\mathbf{W}_2A(\mathbf{x}))\\
\mathbf{W}_1, \mathbf{W}_2\ \ \text{are rank one}\\
\text{trace}(\mathbf{W}_1)=\text{trace}(\mathbf{W}_2)=1\\
\mathbf{W}_1\succeq 0,\ \ \mathbf{W}_2\succeq 0\\
\mathbf{W}_1+\mathbf{W}_2\ \ \text{is rank two}\\
\text{trace}((\mathbf{W}_1-\mathbf{W}_2)A(\mathbf{x}))\geq 0$$

Then, I have trouble achieving the final goal: an SDP with a rank-$1$ constraint and stuck with some bilinear terms. Can anyone provide some next-step suggestions or further hints?

Comment: A problem with your last step: $W_1 + W_2$ being rank two is necessary but not sufficient to guarantee that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal.  We would need a  condition like $\operatorname{tr}(W_1W_2) = 0$.

Comment: In the exercise problem, are we given the largest eigenvalue/eigenvector?

Comment: According to your link, your problem can be formulated as
$$
\max_A \operatorname{trace}(AX)\\
A \succeq 0, \quad A \preceq I\\
\operatorname{trace}(A) = 2
$$
However, this doesn't match up with the "rank one constraint" hint.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the reply and correction. The exercise problem was posted here http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF523/ORF523_Lec10.pdf (see the last page)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think your lastly proposed reformulation minimizes the sum of the first and second largest eigenvalues but not the second largest eigenvalue only.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Correction: the problem is posted on Page 8, not the last page. Sorry for the confusion.